# ¿Como puedo omitir un elemento de una lista dentro de un ciclo for?

Tags: python

Necesito hacer print de todos los elementos a excepción de los tipo booleano:

```
lista=["oveja","vaca",True,"perro",False]

for animal in lista:
    if type(animal)==bool:
        break
    print(animal)
```

pero se detiene en "vaca" y no sigue mas, ¿Cómo puedo seguir?

Comment: cambia a `if type(animal)==bool: print(animal)` o mejor a `if isinstance(animal, bool): 
 print(animal)`

Comment: `print([l for l in lista if type(l) != bool])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The break statement, like in C, breaks out of the innermost enclosing for or while loop.

[Documentación.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Tu `break` termina el ciclo `for`.

Solución:

```
lista=["oveja","vaca",True,"perro",False]

for animal in lista:
    if type(animal)!=bool:
        print(animal)
```

Answer (score 2):

Al utilizar la sentencia `break`, estás rompiendo el bucle `for`, como dicen arriba. Utilizando la sentencia `continue`, el programa se saltará la línea `print(animal)` cada vez que el elemento de la lista que le toque recorrer sea un booleano y continuará con el bucle.

```
lista=["oveja","vaca",True,"perro",False]

for animal in lista:
    if type(animal)==bool:
        continue
    print(animal)
```